# Sound Generation App Problem - Not able to generate sound for > 6000 Hz sound frequency

Tags: java, android, audio

I am a medical student trying to create a simple hearing test for poor patients in India who cannot find any doctors due to COVID challenges. I have asked someone's help in creating this app but for some reason I am not able to hear the 8000 Hz sound (all other frequencies working well). Any suggestion on what maybe going wrong?

This is the SoundGenerator file code
...

```
class SoundGenerator {

    private fun generateTone(freqHz: Float, durationMs: Int, channel: Channel): AudioTrack {
        val count = (44100.0 * 2.0 * (durationMs / 1000.0)).toInt() and 1.inv()
        val samples = ShortArray(count)
        var i = 0
        while (i < count) {
            val sample = (sin(2.0 * Math.PI * i.toDouble() / (44100.0 / freqHz)) * 0x7FFF).toShort()
            when(channel) {
                Channel.LEFT -> {
                    samples[i + 0] = sample
                    samples[i + 1] = 0
                }
                Channel.RIGHT -> {
                    samples[i + 0] = 0
                    samples[i + 1] = sample
                }
            }
            i += 2
        }

        val track = AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            count * (java.lang.Short.SIZE / 8), AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC
        )

        track.write(samples, 0, count)

        return track
    }


    fun playSound(freqHz: Float, db: Float, channel: Channel): AudioTrack {
        val tone = generateTone(freqHz, durationMs, channel)
        val volume = 0.5f / 90.0f * db

        tone.setVolume(volume)

        return tone
    }

    companion object {
        const val durationMs = 250
    }

    enum class Channel {
        LEFT, RIGHT
    }
}
```

...

And this is the Hearing Test file code

...

```
package com.icanhear.icanhear

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Environment
import android.text.TextUtils
import com.icanhear.icanhear.models.State
import com.icanhear.icanhear.models.UserInfo
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class HearingTest(
    private val stateChangeListener: StateChangeListener
) {

    private val frequencies = arrayListOf(
        500.0f,
        1000.0f,
        2000.0f,
        3000.0f,
        4000.0f,
        6000.0f,
        6001.0f,
        8000.0f
    )

    private val dBMin = 20.0f
    private val dBMax = 90.0f
    private val dBStep = 10.0f
    private val dBAccurateStep = 5.0f

    var currentChannel = SoundGenerator.Channel.RIGHT
    var currentDb = dBMax
    var frequencyIndex = 0

    var currentState: State? = null

    var confirmation = 0

    var approxStop = 0.0f

    val rightEarResults = ArrayList<State>()
    val leftEarResults = ArrayList<State>()

    fun start() {
        approxStop = 0.0f
        frequencyIndex = 0
        currentDb = dBMax
        invalidateState()
    }

    fun end() {
        currentState?.let {
            when (currentChannel) {
                SoundGenerator.Channel.LEFT -> {
                    leftEarResults.add(it)
                }
                SoundGenerator.Channel.RIGHT -> {
                    rightEarResults.add(it)
                }
            }
        }
        notifyStateChanged()

        if (currentChannel == SoundGenerator.Channel.RIGHT) {
            currentChannel = SoundGenerator.Channel.LEFT
            start()
        } else {
            finish()
        }

    }

    private fun finish() {
        stateChangeListener.onFinish()
    }

    fun yes() {
        if (frequencyIndex >= frequencies.size) {
            end()
        } else {
            if (approxStop == currentDb) {
                confirmation += 1
                if (confirmation == 3) {
                    if (frequencyIndex + 1 < frequencies.size) {
                        next()
                    } else {
                        end()
                    }
                    return
                }
            } else {
                confirmation = 1
                approxStop = currentDb
            }

            if (currentDb > dBMin) {
                currentDb -= if (currentDb - dBStep > dBMin) {
                    dBStep
                } else {
                    dBAccurateStep
                }
                invalidateState()
            } else {
                currentDb = dBMax
                if (frequencyIndex + 1 < frequencies.size) {
                    next()
                } else {
                    end()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun no() {
        if (currentDb + dBAccurateStep < dBMax) {
            currentDb += dBAccurateStep
            invalidateState()
        } else {
            currentDb = dBMax
            approxStop = 0.0f
            confirmation = 0
            if (frequencyIndex + 1 >= frequencies.size) {
                end()
            } else {
                next()
            }
        }
    }

    fun next() {
        currentState?.let {
            when (currentChannel) {
                SoundGenerator.Channel.LEFT -> {
                    leftEarResults.add(it)
                }
                SoundGenerator.Channel.RIGHT -> {
                    rightEarResults.add(it)
                }
            }
        }
        approxStop = 0.0f
        currentDb = dBMax
        confirmation = 0
        frequencyIndex += 1
        invalidateState()
    }

    private fun invalidateState() {
        currentState = State(frequencies[frequencyIndex], currentDb, currentChannel)
        notifyStateChanged()
    }

    private fun notifyStateChanged() {
        currentState?.let {
            var progress = frequencyIndex + 1
            if (currentChannel == SoundGenerator.Channel.LEFT) {
                progress += frequencies.size
            }
            stateChangeListener.onChanged(it, frequencies.size * 2, progress, approxStop, confirmation)
        }
    }

    fun saveResult(context: Context): String {
        val userInfo = UserInfo.instance

        val date = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd.MM.YYYY", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

        val pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val appDirectory = File(pathToExternalStorage.absolutePath + "/documents/HearingTest")
        appDirectory.mkdirs()

        val fileName = "HearingTest $date.txt"

        File(appDirectory, fileName).bufferedWriter().use { out ->
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.name)) {
                out.write("${context.getString(R.string.name)}: ${userInfo.name}")
                out.newLine()
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.location)) {
                out.write("${context.getString(R.string.location)}: ${userInfo.location}")
                out.newLine()
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.age)) {
                out.write("${context.getString(R.string.age)}: ${userInfo.age}")
                out.newLine()
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.email)) {
                out.write("${context.getString(R.string.email)}: ${userInfo.email}")
                out.newLine()
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.phone)) {
                out.write("${context.getString(R.string.phone)}: ${userInfo.phone}")
                out.newLine()
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userInfo.medicalHistory)) {
                out.write("${context.getString(R.string.medical_history)}: ${userInfo.medicalHistory}")
                out.newLine()
            }

            out.newLine()

            out.write("${context.getString(R.string.right_ear)}:")
            out.newLine()
            rightEarResults.forEach { result ->
                out.write(result.toString())
                out.newLine()
            }

            out.newLine()

            out.write("${context.getString(R.string.left_ear)}:")
            out.newLine()
            leftEarResults.forEach { result ->
                out.write(result.toString())
                out.newLine()
            }
        }
        return fileName
    }
}
```

...

Comment: Are you testing this on an Android phone ? It’s possible that the phone’s speaker has a poor frequency response at 8 kHz and beyond, so it may just be a hardware limitation. Try it with decent earphones and see if that helps.

Comment: Paul - thanks for the response...I am testing it on phone as well as on a laptop phone simulator. For some reason, I am not able to hear any frequency above 6100 Hz (when I add more frequencies in the "frequencies" table). If I add 6000 two times, then it still works (which suggests to a neophyte like me that the code is working ok, i.e. no problem in arracy allocation etc.) but for some reason no sound coming out at that frequency. My Google searches suggest that Android phones can play those frequencies closer to 8000Hz but I just hear a "click" at that point of testing. Any ideas?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of (apart from the remote possibility that you have a hearing problem!) is that perhaps your sample rate is actually 16 kHz and your sound API is emulating a full 44.1 kHz sample rate - I know nothing about Android, its audio API or the hardware though, so this is just a wild guess.

Comment: Paul. - thanks anyway. My hearing (thankfully!) is ok - I am an ENT doctor :-) I will try to read up more about the sample rate and how this code is generating sound samples to try to understand your suggestion (it is greek to me right now!). Thanks again

Comment: I think my “wild guess” above is probably wrong - from reading up a little on Android it seems most devices operate at either 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz. I used to write software for hearing research, so I understand a lot of the pitfalls, and would like to be able to help you solve this, but unfortunately I know nothing about Android. Feel free to add me on LinkedIn if you like though (see my profile).